# How to reset the Pagination's current page when pageSize changes in Ant Design?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

**My requirement:** when `pageSize` changes (with `onShowSizeChange`), reset the `current` to 1, instead of preserving the `current` (like the default behavior). How to do that with [Ant Design `Pagination`](https://ant.design/components/pagination/)?

E.g: I'm in `pageSize=10,current=2`, when changing `pageSize` from 10 to 20, I want `current` to be reset to 1, instead of still being 2.

My code:

```
function App() {
  const [current, setCurrent] = React.useState(1);

  return (
    <Pagination
      current={current}
      onChange={setCurrent}
      showSizeChanger={true}
      onShowSizeChange={() => setCurrent(1)}
      total={1000}
    />
  );
}
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-antd-4-17-0-alpha-7-forked-yd9r7)

Comment: is your `pageSize` a dynamic value? in the sandbox, with every change on `pageSize` property, the whole `App` will re-render.

Answer (score 4):

Many thanks to all the answerers, all are very insightful and really helped me to solve the problem. Cause my real code involves storing `pageSize` as a state as well, here's my final solution based on their answers (which will get rid of *onShowSizeChange* altogether):

```
function App() {
  const [current, setCurrent] = React.useState(1);
  const pageSizeRef = React.useRef(10);

  return (
    <Pagination
      current={current}
      defaultPageSize={pageSizeRef.current}
      onChange={(newCurrent, newPageSize) => {
        const pageSizeChange = pageSizeRef.current !== newPageSize;
        if (pageSizeChange) {
          setCurrent(1);
        } else {
          setCurrent(newCurrent);
        }
        pageSizeRef.current = newPageSize;
      }}
      showSizeChanger={true}
      total={1000}
    />
  );
}
```

---

Re-explanation:

Look at [the internal implementation](https://github.com/react-component/pagination/blob/ca84b62517e3447db1c4326dc3e9d7b599615034/src/Pagination.jsx), when *changePageSize*, it'll call *props.onShowSizeChange* and *props.onChange* with the order of ***props.onShowSizeChange* first and *props.onChange* later**. And I had `setCurrent` inside *props.onChange* as well so it overrode the `setCurrent(1)` in *props.onShowSizeChange*. So the possible solutions are:

1. Make the *setCurrent* inside *props.onShowSizeChange* being fired after with *setTimeout* (thanks @nearhuscarl)
2. Ignore handling for pageSize changes inside *onChange* and only handle it in *onShowSizeChange* (thanks @lith)
3. Handle pageSize changes inside *onChange* instead of handling it in *onShowSizeChange* (what I ended up with)

Answer (score 1):

Its a simple issue that gets really annoying with AntD

The `onChange` fires whenever anything changes in the pagination not only when changing page number. Meaning, when you change the page size, it triggers both `onShowSizeChange` AND `onChange`. But `onChange` has highter priority hence it triggers last. So it sets the page back to the same one.

Now there are multiple fixes to do. For me, personalty, I do not use antd provided page sizer in pagination and i use my own custom made using `select`. But there are other solutions.

If you use `onChange` purply only for page changing then there is a simple solution - filter if the page actually changed.

In this case, if you change your page, the provided variable on `onChange` and your state variable `current` will not match, but if you change the page size, the page will remain the same with `current`. This allows to do a simple `if` check.

```
onChange={(pageNum) => pageNum !== current && setCurrent(pageNum)}
```

This way if the page number and the current page number is the same, `onChange` will not change the page number (to the same one) and trigger a re-render. Its good, because it also saves on performance to not re-trigger same re-renders when nothing changed. This also allows for the `onShowSizeChange` to kick in without being overridden.

```
<Pagination
      current={current}
      onChange={(pageNum) => pageNum !== current && setCurrent(pageNum)}
      showSizeChanger={true}
      onShowSizeChange={() => setCurrent(1)}
      total={1000}
/>
```

BUT there is an issue. If you are on the last page and you change the page size - the page number will be different, by antD calculations, and hence the if will not prevent it. So the first method would be a better one.

There is, also, a  3rd method, that I can think of. But its a hacky one. Would not use it in a big App. But its not bad. Adding 2 new methods. `sizeChangeLogic` that is responsible for size change logic code.

```
const sizeChangeLogic = (current, size) => {
    setSize = true;
    setCurrent(1);
  };
```

and `onChangeLogic` method for on change logic code

```
const onChangeLogic = (current, size) => {
    !setSize && setCurrent(current);
  };
```

and also include a new variable `let setSize = false;` after `useState`.

NOTE this new variable canNOT be a state. Ill explain why soon.

and the pagination itself:

```
<Pagination
  current={current}
  onShowSizeChange={sizeChangeLogic}
  onChange={onChangeLogic}
  showSizeChanger={true}
  total={1000}
/>
```

The logic here is, since `onShowSizeChange` triggers first, will set the locla variable `setSize` to true and set the page num to 1. Then `onChange` triggers and gets the `setSize` value that is, rn `true`, invert it and check if it can change the number if its `false` then it can. If its `true` (after a size change) `it will not change it. This prevents the previously mentioned bug. After the page number (`current`) changes, it triggers a re-render that triggers the` setSize`to go back to`false` state hence the cycle continues.

The reason you can NOT have `setSize` as a state is because the state value changes AFTER a re-render. So the value from `false` to `true` would not change as both `onchange` methods would be ran before a re-render.

Heres a 3rd method full code:

```
function App() {
  const [current, setCurrent] = React.useState(1);
  let setSize = false;

  const sizeChangeLogic = (current, size) => {
    setSize = true;
    setCurrent(1);
  };

  const onChangeLogic = (current, size) => {
    !setSize && setCurrent(current);
  };

  return (
    <Pagination
      current={current}
      onShowSizeChange={sizeChangeLogic}
      onChange={onChangeLogic}
      showSizeChanger={true}
      total={1000}
    />
  );
}
```

Choose what fits you best.

Answer (score 1):

This is what happens [inside `Pagination`](https://github.com/react-component/pagination/blob/ca84b62517e3447db1c4326dc3e9d7b599615034/src/Pagination.jsx#L234-L238) when the `pageSize` value is changed:

```
this.props.onShowSizeChange(current, size);

if ('onChange' in this.props && this.props.onChange) {
  this.props.onChange(current, size);
}
```

Here is a picture to illustrate what happens:

[image]

Because `onChange` callback notifies when the value of either the current page or pageSize changes, you can control the `pageSize` value and only reset the current `page` if the `pageSize` is different in the last render:

```
const [current, setCurrent] = React.useState(1);
const [pageSize, setPageSize] = React.useState(10);

console.log({ current });

return (
  <Pagination
    current={current}
    pageSize={pageSize}
    onChange={(newPage, newPageSize) => {
      // react batches all setState calls internally so this only costs 1 render
      setPageSize(newPageSize);
      setCurrent(pageSize !== newPageSize ? 1 : newPage);
    }}
    showSizeChanger={true}
    total={1000}
  />
);
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Would not recommend using `setTimeout` for such things. It will cause 2 re-renders that can be bad if fetching data form API - double the fetch. That would require ifs to check and etc. mor elogic then worth

Comment: @Lith that's why it's called a workaround, the real fix here is to file an issue on antd repo and wait for them to release a new version with the bug fixed, my solution is simple and quick to implement and you can isolate that problematic `Pagination` by separating it in a wrapper component. If your application is having a performance issue because of an extra render, then react is not worthy to use.

Comment: IMO there are better workarounds that do not cause massive amounts of code, possibilities of performance lost and extra re-renders. As if the user would use, lets say, `useEffect` to execute an API fetch on `current` change then it would require double the fetching and that's not optimal for both application and user. Adding more code to try to resolve this just increase the amount of code that is unneeded. Hence why its good to keep re-renders to a minimum. Not saying your solution is terrible, or that it wouldn't work or etc. I'm just sharing my opinion over it.

Comment: @Lith the API refetching is not an issue here since you can supply a dependency array, even if the component is rendered multiple times unnecessarily, the callback in `useEffect` only fires when the `current` value changes. Of course in a real codebase, I'd expect to see a comment explaining the reason why this code exists because workaround codes is usually not pretty to look at.

Comment: @Lith actually Loi's approach is better, I've improved my answer based on his suggestion.